# Changing subsection numbering within a chapter

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have chapters and I want the subsection numbering to correspond to the chapter numbering..

for example:

```
Chapter 1

1.1 blah blah
1.2 hello
```

At the moment, I have:

```
Chapter 1

1 blah blah
2 hello
```

Here is my preamble code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{1.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
```

Then after a title page, TOC, abstract etc..

```
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

{\newgeometry{left=0.98in,right=0.98in,top=0.98in,bottom=0.78in}
%\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

I just use `\section` to create the sections.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}`. This adds the chapter counter value to the section counter output. You do mean `section` and not `subsection` as in the 1st line of your post, don't you?

Comment: In addition to my comment above: Please always post minimal working examples, not just fragments of preambles and document bodies.

Comment: Yes, I meant section. Thanks Chris! I will do that from now on.

Comment: What you want (`section` counter subordinated to `chapter` counter) is the default in the `report` document class but you are overriding this with `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`, simply delete that line from your code.

Comment: Also, I know that you've upvoted answers and that's great, but please consider revisiting your questions and accepting the answers that you consider solved your problems (accepting and up-voting are two different actions). In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 1):

What you want (`section` counter subordinated to `chapter` counter) is the default in the `report` document class but you are overriding this with this line in your code:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

simply delete that line from your code.